# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host :443 ssl default[None]

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm currently trying to use a proxy using aiohttp, when I remove proxy configuration it works, but when I add it back, it fails.

My proxy url is correct, I've validated that by simply using python-requests, call worked fine.

```
async with session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, proxy=proxy['http'], proxy_auth=proxy_auth) as response:
```

Exact Error Messag:

```
   raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host [somewebsite]:443 ssl:default [None]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [aiohttp.client\_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host stackoverflow.com:443 ssl:default \[Connect call failed ('151.101.193.69', 443)\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347818/aiohttp-client-exceptions-clientconnectorerror-cannot-connect-to-host-stackover)