# Cannot connect to host. Heroku and discord bot problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a discord music bot with python using wavelink. When I started this app for the first time on my computer it works fine, but yesterday I wanted to deploy it to heroku and it wasn't working, so I was trying to run it again, just on my computer, with the same code and now it's not working at all. I think the code is totally the same like for the first time, but everytime I run the bot there is:

> WEBSOCKET | Connection Failure:: Cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1:2333
> ssl:default [Komputer zdalny odrzucił połączenie sieciowe] Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 936, in
> _wrap_create_connection
> return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa   File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 1021, in create_connection
> raise exceptions[0]   File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1006, in create_connection
> sock = await self._connect_sock(   File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 920, in _connect_sock
> await self.sock_connect(sock, address)   File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 702, in sock_connect
> return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)   File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 808, in _poll
> value = callback(transferred, key, ov)   File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 595, in finish_connect
> ov.getresult() ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 1225] Komputer zdalny odrzucił połączenie sieciowe
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\wavelink\websocket.py", line 76, in
> _connect
> self._websocket = await self._node.session.ws_connect(uri, headers=self.headers, heartbeat=self._node.heartbeat)   File
> "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 721, in
> _ws_connect
> resp = await self.request(method, url,   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request
> conn = await self._connector.connect(   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in
> connect
> proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 858, in
> _create_connection
> _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in
> _create_direct_connection
> raise last_exc   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in
> _create_direct_connection
> transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 943, in
> _wrap_create_connection
> raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host
> 127.0.0.1:2333 ssl:default [Komputer zdalny odrzucił połączenie sieciowe]

I think the problem is with this part of code:

```
async def start_nodes(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

        # Initiate our nodes. For this example we will use one server.
        # Region should be a discord.py guild.region e.g sydney or us_central (Though this is not technically required)
        await self.bot.wavelink.initiate_node(host='127.0.0.1',
                                              port=2333,
                                              rest_uri='http://127.0.0.1:2333',
                                              password='youshallnotpass',
                                              identifier='TEST',
                                              region='europe')
```

File application.yml looks like that:

```
server: # REST and WS server
  port: 2333
  address: 0.0.0.0
lavalink:
  server:
    password: "youshallnotpass"
    sources:
      youtube: true
      bandcamp: true
      soundcloud: true
      twitch: true
      vimeo: true
      mixer: true
      http: true
      local: false
    bufferDurationMs: 400
    youtubePlaylistLoadLimit: 6 # Number of pages at 100 each
    playerUpdateInterval: 5 # How frequently to send player updates to clients, in seconds
    youtubeSearchEnabled: true
    soundcloudSearchEnabled: true
    gc-warnings: true
    #ratelimit:
      #ipBlocks: ["1.0.0.0/8", "..."] # list of ip blocks
      #excludedIps: ["...", "..."] # ips which should be explicit excluded from usage by lavalink
      #strategy: "RotateOnBan" # RotateOnBan | LoadBalance | NanoSwitch | RotatingNanoSwitch
      #searchTriggersFail: true # Whether a search 429 should trigger marking the ip as failing
      #retryLimit: -1 # -1 = use default lavaplayer value | 0 = infinity | >0 = retry will happen this numbers times

metrics:
  prometheus:
    enabled: false
    endpoint: /metrics

sentry:
  dsn: ""
  environment: ""
#  tags:
#    some_key: some_value
#    another_key: another_value

logging:
  file:
    max-history: 30
    max-size: 1GB
  path: ./logs/

  level:
    root: INFO
    lavalink: INFO
```

Do you have any ideas?

SOLUTION: Okay, if you have the same problem as me and you are using Lavalink, you have to start the Lavalink server at first. In my case, I have to type in terminal "java -jar Lavalink.jar" to start the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347818/aiohttp-client-exceptions-clientconnectorerror-cannot-connect-to-host-stackover

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but then i figured it out

you need to setup Lavalink

1. Download [OpenJDK 13.0.2](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) and then extract
2. Download [Lavalink](https://ci.fredboat.com/viewLog.html?buildId=lastSuccessful&buildTypeId=Lavalink_Build&tab=artifacts&guest=1)
3. Paste `Lavalink.jar` inside bin from the 1st step

```
mv ./Lavalink.jar ./open-jdk/bin
```

4. create a new file `application.yml` and paste [this code](https://github.com/Frederikam/Lavalink/blob/master/LavalinkServer/application.yml.example) 
   - make sure to change `address: 0.0.0.0` to `address: 127.0.0.1`

```yaml
server: # REST and WS server
  port: 2333
  address: 127.0.0.1
lavalink:
  server:
    password: "youshallnotpass"
    sources:
      youtube: true
      bandcamp: true
      soundcloud: true
      twitch: true
      vimeo: true
      http: true
      local: false
    bufferDurationMs: 400
    youtubePlaylistLoadLimit: 6 # Number of pages at 100 each
    playerUpdateInterval: 5 # How frequently to send player updates to clients, in seconds
    youtubeSearchEnabled: true
    soundcloudSearchEnabled: true
    gc-warnings: true
    #ratelimit:
      #ipBlocks: ["1.0.0.0/8", "..."] # list of ip blocks
      #excludedIps: ["...", "..."] # ips which should be explicit excluded from usage by lavalink
      #strategy: "RotateOnBan" # RotateOnBan | LoadBalance | NanoSwitch | RotatingNanoSwitch
      #searchTriggersFail: true # Whether a search 429 should trigger marking the ip as failing
      #retryLimit: -1 # -1 = use default lavaplayer value | 0 = infinity | >0 = retry will happen this numbers times

metrics:
  prometheus:
    enabled: false
    endpoint: /metrics

sentry:
  dsn: ""
  environment: ""
#  tags:
#    some_key: some_value
#    another_key: another_value

logging:
  file:
    max-history: 30
    max-size: 1GB
  path: ./logs/

  level:
    root: INFO
    lavalink: INFO
```

5. go to command prompt and execute below command

```
pip install discord.py[voice] wavelink
```

6. open the folder where you extracted JDK  and then type

```
java -jar Lavalink.jar
```

this will start the lavalink server and then you will be able to use your bot

---

for more help check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGeu_IS0o1A&t=269s)

Comment: Yes! True, I figured it out, but thank you for the answer!

Comment: @fajferek hey you said that you figured it out. I am having an issue where I cannot connect to localhost. What was your resolution?

Comment: @wjvukasovic
It works for me - > java -jar Lavalink.jar
You have to type it before run your bot.