# OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable in pythonanywhere with asyncio and aiohttp

Tags: python, api, pythonanywhere, py-telegram-bot-api

I have deployed in pythonanywhere an application that consists of a telegram bot that connects to api.scryfall.com through scrython, a api wrapper (which uses asyncio and aiohttp).
The app works perfectly on my computer but when I try to use it from pythonanywhere I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 986, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs) # type: ignore[return-value] # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1056, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1041, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 955, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 507, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrython/cards/named.py", line 57, in __init__
    super(Named, self).__init__(self.url)
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrython/foundation.py", line 36, in __init__
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrython/foundation.py", line 32, in main
    self.scryfallJson = await getRequest(client, self._url)
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrython/foundation.py", line 27, in getRequest
    async with client.get(url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._chorus
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 535, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 542, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 907, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/rayolaser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 992, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.scryfall.com:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]
```

Comment: have you read pythonanywhere documents about network restrictions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [aiohttp.client\_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host stackoverflow.com:443 ssl:default \[Connect call failed ('151.101.193.69', 443)\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347818/aiohttp-client-exceptions-clientconnectorerror-cannot-connect-to-host-stackover)